# validation on button click event wpf c#

Tags: wpf, validation, combobox, textbox

I have a WPF application where I have to check a `TextBox` value and a `ComboBox`. if it is empty or not on to the format the button click event should fire an error and if the selected index is 0 in the `ComboBox` again it should fire an error.(like in error provider).

I did many research on the internet I came across with the solution with *IDataErrorInfo*. But the problem is how do i do this on the button click event. All of the examples are doing it on the form load.

I'm quite new for WPF. following is my code

```
public class ClientMap : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string CDSNo { get; set; }

    public ClientMap(int ID)
    {
        Id = ID;
    }
    public ClientMap()
    {

    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "CDSNo")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CDSNo))
                    result = "Please enter a CDS No";
                else
                {
                    string regEx = "[A-Z]{3}-\\d{9}-[A-Z]{2}-\\d{2}";
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(CDSNo, regEx))
                    {
                        result = "Invalid CDS No";
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CE.Data.Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public CE.Data.Institute Institute { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

}
```

and XAML is

```
<Window.Resources>
    <validation:ClientMap x:Key="data"/>
</Window.Resources>

<control:AutoCompleteTextBox Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="CDSNo" Source="{StaticResource data}"
                ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"   
                UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">

            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</control:AutoCompleteTextBox>
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html) you will need to create your validation classes, the last part of the article discusses how to manual trigger the validation.

Comment: Thanks @MarkHall.. Will give it a try and let you know...

Comment: Still no luck.. I have set _UpdateSourceTrigger_  to Explicit and I have added  textboxName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource(); to the button click event. but still the text box has a red colour border at the form load. if i enter a valid text it goes off...

Comment: I made a quick demo and I can not duplicate your problem, It loads up without validation errors and only shows the error when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post the code please? Just want to know whats wrong with my code..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is modified code from this [article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules). You will need to get the references and additional classes from the download available from that site.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SOTCBindingValidation.Window1" x:Name="This"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOTCBindingValidation"
    Title="SOTC Validation Test" Height="184" Width="390">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ErrorsToMessageConverter x:Key="eToMConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Margin="2">Enter An IPv4 Address:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddressBox">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding ElementName="This" Path="IPAddress" 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:IPv4ValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" 
            Text="{Binding ElementName=AddressBox, 
                          Path=(Validation.Errors),
                          Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}" />
            <Button Name="Btn1" Height ="30" Width="70" Click="Btn1_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace SOTCBindingValidation
{

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IPAddressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IPAddress", typeof(string),
            typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

        public string IPAddress
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(IPAddressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IPAddressProperty, value); }
        }

        public Window1()
        { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ForceValidation();
            if (!Validation.GetHasError(AddressBox))
            {
                // Put the code you want to execute if the validation succeeds here
            }
        }
        private void ForceValidation()
        {
            AddressBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi... I tried this. If you can notice that the text box is loaded with a default (1.1.1.1) this works.. but when I  removed the default it did not work. In my scenario, text box is initially blank and I just want to validate input string....

Comment: @Sri If you notice the UIPropertyMetadata I changed it from 1.1.1.1 to "" and it works correctly.

Comment: @Sri Even doing this still works `public static readonly DependencyProperty IPAddressProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("IPAddress", typeof(string),
      typeof(Window1));`

Comment: can you please look in to my code in my post and let me know whats wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Manage to get the code working.. only problem is that the button click event execute all the code even the validation is failed..

Comment: @Sri What code are you talking about. I thought you just wanted to manually validate with the button click

Comment: @Sri use Validation.GetHasError(ControlName) to check if validation has failed please see edit